# make downloading text in codemirror textarea

Tags: javascript, codemirror

How to make a downloading text in codemirror textarea?

Answer (score 1):

CodeMirror is a custom component, so you'll have to go through its interface, rather than the DOM interface, to interact with it. If you save the object that you get when you create your editor instance, you can do `editor.execCommand("selectAll")` to select the whole editor, or `.getValue()` to get the content, etcetera.